# Clicking button get NullPointerException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, awt

I`m trying to save entered in gui information in a text file. 
The error I get is a

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

As I understand, when I click the OK button, the 
button doesn't receive anything and that's why I get a nullPointerException.
Where is a mistake?

Here is a JPanel class that manages JTextFields.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class LibraryTextfieldsPanel extends JPanel{
private JTextField copyID;
private JTextField ISBN;
private JTextField author;


public LibraryTextfieldsPanel() {
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    Container choiceBox = new Container();

    this.add(new JLabel("Copy ID "));
copyID = new JTextField();
this.add(copyID);

    this.add(new JLabel("ISBN "));
ISBN = new JTextField();
this.add(ISBN);

    this.add(new JLabel("Author "));
author = new JTextField();
this.add(author);`enter code here`

}

public Integer getCopyID() {
      try {
          return Integer.valueOf(copyID.getText());
      }
      catch(NullPointerException ex) {
          return 0;
      }
      catch(NumberFormatException ex2) {
          return 0;
      }
    }


public Integer getISBN() {
    try {
          return Integer.valueOf(ISBN.getText());
      }
      catch(NullPointerException ex) {
          return 0;
      }
      catch(NumberFormatException ex2) {
          return 0;
      }
    }


public String getAuthor() {
    return author.getText();
}
```

}

This is my Button Panel class that should receive the data from LibraryTextfieldsPanel.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class OkButtonPanel extends JPanel {
private JButton ok;
private JButton cancel;
private LibraryRadioPanel radioPanel;
private LibraryTextfieldsPanel textFieldsPanel;
private CategoriesPanel categories; 

public OkButtonPanel(LibraryRadioPanel radioPanel, LibraryTextfieldsPanel textFieldsPanel,
        CategoriesPanel categories) {
    this.setLayout((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    ok = new JButton("OK");
    cancel = new JButton("CANCEL");
    this.add(ok);
    this.add(cancel);
    this.radioPanel = radioPanel;
    this.textFieldsPanel = textFieldsPanel;
    this.categories = categories;

    ok.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    cancel.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        JButton theButton = (JButton) arg0.getSource();

        if (theButton == ok) {
            Integer copyID = textFieldsPanel.getCopyID();
            Integer  isbn = textFieldsPanel.getISBN();
            String   author = textFieldsPanel.getAuthor();
            try {

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("MyLibrary.txt"));
                out.append(copyID + " " + isbn + " "
                        + author);
                out.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File Not Found Exception");
            }

        }else if (theButton == cancel) {
            textFieldsPanel.setVisible(false);

        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which line is the exception thrown? The stack trace printed together with the exception should tell you where the exception happened and you can trace your code accordingly.

Comment: Line 46 in OkButtonPanel which is `Integer copyID = textFieldsPanel.getCopyID();`

Comment: How do you instantiate OkButtonPanel? If the NPE does happen where you say it does, I'm thinking that textFieldsPanel is null at that point.

Comment: But again a complete stack trace would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Based off what you say where the error is happening, it looks like `textFieldsPanel` is `null`. I would check if `textFieldsPanel` is `null` when passing it to `OkButtonPanel()`. If you can, make sure it's not `null` when passing it into `OkButtonPanel`.

```
public OkButtonPanel(LibraryRadioPanel radioPanel, LibraryTextfieldsPanel textFieldsPanel,
        CategoriesPanel categories) {
    this.setLayout((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    ok = new JButton("OK");
    cancel = new JButton("CANCEL");
    this.add(ok);
    this.add(cancel);
    this.radioPanel = radioPanel;
    if(textFieldsPanel == null) { // Should probably make sure it's not passed as null
        // Do something to handle it
    } else {
        this.textFieldsPanel = textFieldsPanel;
    }

    this.categories = categories;

    ok.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    cancel.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
}
```